# Why my list is empty?

Tags: scala

I have this code:

```
    val products = List()

    def loadProducts(report: (Asset, Party, AssetModel, Location, VendingMachineReading)) = {
      report match {
        case (asset, party, assetModel, location, reading) =>

          EvadtsParser.parseEvadts(reading.evadts, result)

          (result.toMap).map(product => ReportData(
            customer = party.name,
            location = location.description,
            asset = asset.`type`,
            category = "",
            product = product._1,
            counter = product._2,
            usage = 0,
            period = "to be defined")).toList
      }
    }

results.foreach(result => products ::: loadProducts(result))
println(products)
```

Can you please tell me what I am doing wrong because products list is empty? If I println `products` inside `loadProducts` method, products is not empty. Is the concatenation I am doing wrong?

PS: I am a scala beginner.

Comment: `:::` yields a new list instead of mutating the one you already have in place.

Comment: @om-nom-nom I thought that it ads elements to the end of my list...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As I've already said, ::: yields a new list instead of mutating the one you already have in place.

[http://take.ms/WDB http://take.ms/WDB](http://take.ms/WDB)

You have two options to go: immutable and mutable

Here is what you can do in immutable and idiomatic style:

```
def loadProducts(report: (...)): List[...] = {
  ...
}

val products = result.flatMap(result => loadProducs(result))
println(products)
```

But also, you can tie with mutability and use ListBuffer to do the things you've wanted:

```
def loadProducts(report: (...)): List[T] = {
  ...
}

val buffer = scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[T]() 
result.foreach(result => buffer ++ = loadProducs(result))
val products = buffer.toList
println(products)
```

P.S. `flatMap( ...)` is an analog to `map(...).flatten`, so don't be confused that I and Tomasz written it so differently.

Answer (score 4):

`List` type is immutable, `val` implies a reference that never changes. Thus you can't really change the contents of `products` reference. I suggest building a "list of lists" first and then flattening:

```
val products = results.map(loadProducts).flatten
println(products)
```

Notice that `map(loadProducts)` is just a shorthand for `map(loadProducts(_))`, which is a shorthand for `map(result => loadProducts(result))`.

If you become more experienced, try `foldLeft()` approach, which continuously builds `products` list just like you wanted to do this:

```
results.foldLeft(List[Int]())((agg, result) => agg ++ loadProducts(result))
```